# Trac - Limited assign permissions

Tags: python, ubuntu, access-control, bitnami, trac

Hello dear Developers,

I recently installed [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) in my workplace, and I currently manage it. So it was all good until I found this requirement which seems to be impossible with trac (with what it comes by default)

I have several groups, and they have different permissions. Suppose they are as below.

```
Super Admin - John
Engineer Admin - Jane, Jack, 
Engineer - Peter, Sam, 
Quality Assurance - Bill, Steve, Rose
```

Now, I want these QA guys to have the ability to create a ticket. That can be done with permissions. But when they create the ticket, I want to limit their privileges to whom they can assign it. That means, They should only be able to assign the ticket to Jane or Jack (or say the Engineer admin Group). Then Jane/Jack will assign it to any Engineer Guy..

That's how I want to manage the flow. But I have no idea how to do this..I searched and found some plugins, but they all are different from what I want.

Can anybody guide me with what to do?

Thanks in advance. Please feel free to ask anything if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to do this with Trac, no plugins needed, but you'll need to enable some *Components* that aren't enabled by default. Hopefully you are using a recent version, preferably Trac 1.0.2.

Enable [extra-permissions-provider](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/ExtraPermissionsProvider):

```
[components]
tracopt.perm.config_perm_provider.extrapermissionsprovider = enabled
```

Create a special permission for the QA group to assign tickets, and for all other users to assign tickets:

```
[extra-permissions]
_perms = TICKET_ASSIGN_QA, TICKET_ASSIGN
```

Grant `TICKET_ASSIGN_QA` to the QA group. Create a special workflow action for the QA group:

```
[ticket-workflow]
qa_reassign = new -> assigned
qa_reassign.name = assign
qa_reassign.operations = set_owner
qa_reassign.set_owner = Jack, Jane
qa_reassign.permission = TICKET_ASSIGN_QA
```

If you're using the default workflow, for the `reassign` operation you'll need to specify a `permission` attribute in the ticket workflow, requiring a permission that the QA group doesn't possess so that they don't see that workflow action. The following also goes in the `[ticket-workflow]` section.

```
reassign.permission = TICKET_ASSIGN
```

This configuration looks tricky, so feel free to follow up if you need more tips.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. actually I'm using  Bitnami Trac 1.0.1, hope this is fine? I added the new line to the trac.ini, but i dont see the permission in the admin?

Comment: Trac 1.0.1 should be fine. You need to enable the *Component*. Answer edited above.

Comment: Oh..ok thanks...I see it now in admin and I added the permission to qa. can you tell me more about that workflow? what should be done next?

Comment: `ExtraPermissionsProvider` allows you to define arbitrary permissions, which can then be assigned to users or groups. You can then require a permission for a workflow action, which will limit the availability of that action to specified users or groups. See [TracWorkflow documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWorkflow).

Comment: If the QA team already have the ticketmodify permission? what will happen? do i have to remove that?

this is what they have right now...
 REPORT_VIEW TICKET_APPEND TICKET_ASSIGN_QA TICKET_MODIFY TICKET_VIEW

Comment: You don't need to revoke `TICKET_MODIFY` from the QA team. You just need to define a different permission that is needed for the `reassign` action in the default workflow. Or, you can remove the default `reassign` action and make custom workflow actions.

Comment: Ok..thank you so much for the support...i will see this some more...i will not forget to accept the answer as soon as i get this thing fixed.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have any other questions. I expect it will take a bit of experimentation to get it just right. If you prefer to edit the workflow through the browser, [TracWorkflowAdminPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWorkflowAdminPlugin) may help.

Comment: One more question, what is the actual relationship between "qa_reassign" in the [ticket-workflow] and TICKET_ASSIGN_QA in [extra-permissions]?? because I don't see any connection between them. how the new workflow effects to the TICKET_ASSIGN_QA?

Comment: `[extra-permissions]` defines the permission. The permission needs to be assigned to the QA group using the `trac-admin` command line tool, or the *Permissions* page in WebAdmin. And finally, I left out one part above, which I will correct now: `qa_reassign.permissions = TICKET_ASSIGN_QA`, which says that a user must have `TICKET_ASSIGN_QA` to see the workflow action.

Comment: I'm posting an extension of this answer to your post on the [trac users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/trac-users/a_Il7M-NP1M/frsFJJ3wJlEJ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65155/discussion-between-rjollos-and-user3571366).

Comment: Hi RjOllos, thank you very much for the support. Actually your answer is the solution for this. I came so close. But my requirement is changed because the qa group's assign permission is changing time to time..they can assign it to admins only when they create the ticket. and after that they should be able to assign it to anyone they want. this looks confusing, so we stick to our old plan :)

Comment: Your new requirement wouldn't be too hard to implement. It would just require a few more workflow actions. If you ever want to give it a try and need some assistance just ping the [trac users mailing list](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList).

Comment: See post on [trac-users](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/trac-users/a_Il7M-NP1M/frsFJJ3wJlEJ) mailing list for more info, including a new feature added to Trac [#11839](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11839).

Comment: Hi Rjollos, I've another problem..can you help me?

Comment: Sure, but please create a new SO thread if it's a new issue. If you tag the thread with `trac` I will see it. Alternatively, you could ask your question on the [TracUsers mailing list](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList).